# SwiftUI: Button with image got gray border on real iPhone but works fine on simulation mode

Tags: ios, button, swiftui, view, label

I'm trying to make simple app, the app seems working well on simulation mode, but test on my iPhone the button looks different from simulation iPhone,

link the simulation picture here,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyBDM.png)

this is the what I see on the simulation but real iPhone looks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1HLd.png)

please, check the pictures linked,

The button image made on sub View struct and called as a Button label,

plus I tried borderlessbuttonstyle, back and foreground color match both super, and child view. I got nothing, here the code,

I don't know how to delete the gray border not only these buttons but also all buttons that I used with image labeling looks the same way - bordered with gray rectangle,

here the button code

```
struct MainList: View {
@EnvironmentObject var pageControl: PageControl
var body: some View {
    VStack{
        Button{
            pageControl.pageNum = 1
            pageControl.detailPage = 0
            print("button pressed pageNum: \(pageControl.pageNum), startPage \(pageControl.detailPage)")
        } label: {
            mainListRow(actuator: actuators[0])
                .background(.white)
         }
        .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
        .foregroundColor(.white)
```

and this is the View that used to button label

```
struct mainListRow: View {
var actuator: Actuator
var body: some View {
    HStack(alignment: .center) {
        Image("home")
        Spacer()
        VStack {
            ZStack{
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0)
                    .frame(width: 60, height: 30)
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                Text(String(actuator.speed) + " %")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

---

here add the another picture when I change the background color

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wSD3.png)

as you can see that those three buttons, for the top button without background color, the button area is filled gray color, if I add background color - second button, it only filled inside, so I changed the background color to button field with black then the border color changed. thus I add the background color with white at button field not working - third button :(. the tested phone is iPhone Xs. this is really weird as I mentioned it work fine on simulation. please. test it on real iPhone.

here the code for third picture,

```
            Button{
            pageControl.pageNum = 1
            pageControl.detailPage = 0
            print("button pressed pageNum: \(pageControl.pageNum), startPage \(pageControl.detailPage)")
        } label: {
            mainListRow(actuator: actuators[0])
        }
        .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
        Divider()
        Button{
            pageControl.pageNum = 1
            pageControl.detailPage = 1
            print("Rotate button pressed pageNum: \(pageControl.pageNum), startPage \(pageControl.detailPage)")
        } label: {
            mainListRow(actuator: actuators[1])
                .background(.white)
        }
        .background(.black)
        Divider()
        Button{
            pageControl.pageNum = 1
            pageControl.detailPage = 2
            print("Rotate button pressed pageNum: \(pageControl.pageNum), startPage \(pageControl.detailPage)")
        } label: {
            mainListRow(actuator: actuators[2])
                .buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
        }
        .background(.white)
```

and the the button page added to main here

```
struct testPage: View {
var body: some View {
    MainList()
        .frame(width: 330, height: 150)
        .padding(.top, 20)
}
```

}

Comment: Add a minimum reproducible example

Comment: I got this. it is tint color it automatically applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `MainList` get rid of:

```
            .background(.white)
```

Comment: I add more info please check it on real phone.

Answer (score 2):

The gray/overlay on the button is from the button "tint".

To remove it, add the .plain modifier:

```
Button {
}
.buttonStyle(.plain)
```

*As of today **there is a bug in Xcode** and that's why you can't see the tint properly in the simulator or the preview*.

More examples of workarounds here:

https://hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-disable-the-overlay-color-for-images-inside-button-and-navigationlink